# Destructuring in Typescript with undefined values

Tags: typescript, destructuring

I have 2 objects:

```
const a = {
    foo: "foo",
    bar: "bar",
}

const b = {
    foo: "fooooo",
}
```

I want to use destructuring in a method with default undefined values, like so:

```
const c = a or b; // I don't know which one
```

Then I want to do:

```
const { foo, bar } = c;
```

And I want that

- `foo = "fooooo"` and `bar = undefined`
  or
- `foo = "foo"` and `bar = "bar"`

How can I accomplish that with typescript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript won't be smart enough to deduct that `{foo: string, bar: string} | {foo: string}` can be written as `{foo: string, bar?: string}`, so you'll need to type `c` yourself as follows:

```
const c: { foo: string, bar?: string } = Math.random() > .5 ? a : b; // doesn't matter which
const { foo, bar } = c;
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I don't want `c` to have the `bar` property. That's why I wanted the destructuring to return `undefined`, so `c` would still not have the `bar` property. I guess I'll have to create a wrapper function for that. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean? `c` might have the `bar` property whether you want to or not, if you set `c` to be `a`, it's going to have it... If not, it will get `undefined`.